# I want to add some those given code on function read

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to add this code

```
if(empty($this->session->userdata('isAdmin')))
{
    $this->db->where('user_id',$this->session->userdata('id'));
}
```

on function `read()`.  Can anyone help?

```
public function read()
{
    return $this->db->select("a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*")
           ->from("trip AS a")
           ->join('fleet_type AS b', 'a.type = b.id')
           ->join('trip_route AS c', 'a.route = c.id')
           ->join('shedule AS d', 'a.shedule_id = d.shedule_id')
           ->limit($limit, $start)
           ->get()
           ->result();
}
```

Comment: follow the docs at https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html if you don't chain you can use the if clause

Answer (score 1):

just separate the condition like

```
    public function read ( ) {
     $this->db->select("a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*")
       ->from("trip AS a")
       ->join('fleet_type AS b', 'a.type = b.id')
       ->join('trip_route AS c', 'a.route = c.id')
       ->join('shedule AS d', 'a.shedule_id = d.shedule_id');

     if(empty($this->session->userdata('isAdmin'))) {
      $this->db->where('user_id',$this->session->userdata('id'));
     }

     $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
     $_result = $this->db->get()->result();

     return $_result;
    }
```